# Add to interest list via the Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I'm relatively new to facebook API, but would like to know how to allow a user to add a page to "Interest Lists" through the API, or social plugins? For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Is how to like, and I understand that is basic but anything just so I can allow a user to add a liked page to their interest list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**API**

You can't post to the interests connection. It's not supported in the Graph API.

Your app can *retrieve* a user's interests with the GET request

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/interests
```

You'll need the

```
user_interests
friends_interests
```

permissions.

However, you can't post to the interests connection. You'll get the GraphMethodException "Unsupported post request" in return if you try.

**Social Plug-ins**

None of the [Social Plug-ins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) has posting to interests as a feature.